# How to disable the function of using arrow key to switch focus of controls when developing a Flet app?

Tags: events, keyboard, hover, focus, flet

I noticed that when I was using arrow keys in an sample app, the focus (sort of) of control will be changed depending on the direction of arrow key I have pressed. So how can I disable this behaviour?

I looked all information related to keyboard in the documentation (https://flet.dev/docs/) but I could not find anything related. So I come here to ask for help.

To ask to question in another way. How to ignore the keyboard event so that no gui action will be performed. In PyQt,I can do event.ignore() in the keyboard event handler,but I could not find a similar way in Flet.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for it now. I used page.on_keyboard_event and check if the pressed key is an arrow key, then make the interested control (in this case, a TextButton) in focus.